# Check if string contains 3 or more ordered characters in javascript (no regex)

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, loops

Looking for code that can detect if the string has
repeating characters (sss, 333, !!!)
And/or also if it
contains subsequent characters in order such as (345, efg, abc, 789)

I know their exist ways to do it with regex but wanted to know if any algorithm exist that does it with just loops

```
const str="abc123";
//loop through char to determine if it contains subsequent characters like abc...
 //str should return true
//loop through char to determine if it contains repeated characters like bbb...
 //str should return false
```

Comment: Loop through the indexes. Get the character codes at index, index+1, and index+2. Then check if those codes are consecutive.

Comment: You can use the `charCodeAt()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the charCodeAt function provided by JavaScript.
You need to loop through string and compare that is it repeated character or ordered character.

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/krchandarana/pen/qBRNRRv) link.

```js
var str = "abc123";

str = str.toLowerCase();
var len = str.length;
var a = str.charCodeAt(0);

var n = 3;

var isRepeatingCharFound = false;
var isOrderedCharFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i + (n - 1) <= len) {

        var isRepeatingCharFoundTmp = false;
        var isOrderedCharFoundTmp = false;
        for (var j = i; j < i + n; j++) {
            if (str.charCodeAt(i) === str.charCodeAt(j))
                isRepeatingCharFoundTmp = true;
            else
                isRepeatingCharFoundTmp = false;

            if (str.charCodeAt(i) === str.charCodeAt(j) - (n - 1))
                isOrderedCharFoundTmp = true;
            else
                isOrderedCharFoundTmp = false;
        }
        if (isRepeatingCharFoundTmp)
            isRepeatingCharFound = true;
        if (isOrderedCharFoundTmp)
            isOrderedCharFound = true;
    }
}
console.log('Repeating char ' + (isRepeatingCharFound ? 'found' : 'not found'));
console.log('Ordered char ' + (isOrderedCharFound ? 'found' : 'not found'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following code, where the function analyze either returns 0 or the length of the longest sequence that occurs in the input string (with a minimum of 3). In boolean expressions, 0 will evaluate to false and any other number will evaluate to true. I have made 2 versions. In the first you can pass a mode parameter:

- 1 checks for repeating sequences
- 2 checks for subsequent ascending sequences
- 3 checks for subsequent descending sequences

The second version combines these three modes and therefore requires no mode parameter. Here is the first version:

```
const str = "abc123";

function analyze(s, mode) {
  var count = 0, max = 0, diff, step;
  switch(mode) {
    case 1: step = 0; break; /* repeating */
    case 2: step = 1; break; /* subsequent: ascending */
    case 3: step = -1; break; /* subsequent: descending */
    default: step = 0;
  } 
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {    
    if (i > 0) {
      diff = s.charCodeAt(i) - s.charCodeAt(i - 1);
      if (diff == step) count++;
      if ((diff != step || i == s.length - 1) && count > 0) {
        max = Math.max(count + 1, max);
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return (max > 2 ? max : 0);
}

alert(analyze(str, 2));
```

And here is the second version:

```
var str = "aaxyzzzyxwv";

function analyze(s) {
  var count = 0, max = 0, mode_cur = 0, mode_prv = 0, diff;
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {    
    if (i > 0) {
      diff = s.charCodeAt(i) - s.charCodeAt(i - 1);
      switch(diff) {
        case 0: mode_cur = 1; break; /* repeating */
        case 1: mode_cur = 2; break; /* subsequent: ascending */
        case -1: mode_cur = 3; break; /* subsequent: descending */
        default: mode_cur = 0;
      } 
      if (mode_prv != mode_cur) count = 0;
      if (mode_cur) {
        count++;
        max = Math.max(count + 1, max);
      }
    }
    mode_prv = mode_cur;
  }  
  return (max > 2 ? max : 0);
}

alert(analyze(str));
```